# Horizontal Scroll Bar only in Browser?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

TLDR: Document seems to pull up a horizontal scroll bar only outside of Mozilla Dev Tools.

New to web development, the design aspect is very enjoyable but I struggle with fixing responsiveness issues. In this particular document, I seem to only get a horizontal scroll bar while running the document in a browser (tested in chrome and firefox developer edition). Once run in Firefox Developer edition's responsiveness section with certain heights and widths, it seems to not gain a scroll bar until width 1330. I originally believed the issue was due to the image file size but it seems to be something deeper. My goal is to just have this section take all of the available space on the page, but from my understanding, a horizontal scroll bar means that something is overflowing somewhere and I'm unsure of how to correct this.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --transition-duration: 0.3s;
  --font-size-title: calc(2rem + 2vw);
}

html {
  --color-primary: hsl(274, 99%, 72%);
  --color-primary-m: rgb(241, 172, 255);
  --color-secondary: hsl(274, 99%, 72%, 0.6);
  --color-secondary-m: rgba(207, 56, 200, 0.815);
  --color-secondary-m-dark: purple;
  --color-quaternary: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  --color-tertiary: #f6eedf;
  --color-tertiary-m-light: hsla(39, 56%, 92%, 0.55);
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw);
  font-weight: 200;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: var(--color-quaternary);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: calc(0.5rem + 1vw);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all var(--transition-duration) cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  line-height: 1.7;
  width: 100vw;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.header-main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 6;
}

.header-main-nav input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 3rem;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header-main-nav-hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 3rem;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--color-tertiary);
  z-index: 2;
  display: grid;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  animation: main-nav 2s;
}

@keyframes main-nav {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(150rem) rotate(1000deg);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.header-main-nav-hamburger>div {
  position: relative;
  height: 0.3rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  display: grid;
  transition: var(--transition-duration) ease-in-out;
}

.header-main-nav-hamburger>div::before,
.header-main-nav-hamburger>div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  width: 60%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header-main-nav-hamburger>div::before {
  left: 0;
}

.header-main-nav-hamburger>div::after {
  top: 1rem;
  right: 0;
}

.header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked+.header-main-nav-hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked+.header-main-nav-hamburger>div::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked+.header-main-nav-hamburger>div::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover+.header-main-nav-hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.header-main-nav-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.header-main-nav-menu>div {
  background-color: var(--color-secondary-m-dark);
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 70%;
}

.header-main-nav-menu>div>div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked~.header-main-nav-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked~.header-main-nav-menu>div {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.header-main-nav-menu ul li a:link,
.header-main-nav-menu ul li a:visited {
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.header-main-nav-menu ul li a:link::before,
.header-main-nav-menu ul li a:visited::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  background-color: var(--color-tertiary-m-light);
  transition: transform var(--transition-duration) ease-in-out;
}

.header-main-nav-menu ul li a:hover::before,
.header-main-nav-menu ul li a:active:before {
  transform: scaleY(1)
}

section#whytho {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  grid-column: container-start / container-end;
  padding: 10vh 3vw;
  display: grid;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.whytho-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.whytho-content-title {
  font-size: var(--font-size-title);
  padding: 0 2rem 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.whytho-content-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: white;
}

.whytho-content-para {
  color: var(--color-tertiary);
}

.whytho-content img {
  align-self: center;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 70vh;
  object-fit: initial;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  a:link,
  a:visited {
    font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw);
  }
  section#whytho {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>site</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body class="container">
  <main>
    <header id="home">
      <!--Nav-->
      <nav class="header-main-nav">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class="header-main-nav-hamburger">
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-main-nav-menu">
          <div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">L2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">L3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">L4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">L5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">L6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <section id="whytho">
        <div class="whytho-content">
          <img src="pics/image.jpg" id="img">
          <p class="whytho-content-para">(Image caption) (Colorized 2020.)</p>
          <h2 class="whytho-content-title">But, why a website?</h2>
          <p class="whytho-content-para">Websites bad</p>
          <p class="whytho-content-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you tried changing .container { width: 100vw;} to .container {width: 100%;} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
      display: grid;
      line-height: 1.7;
      width: 100vw;
    } 

/* Because of this width horizontal scroll bar is appear. You can either delete this property or write like this - */

.container {
      ​display: grid;
      ​line-height: 1.7;
      ​ width: 100%;
   ​} 

/* or Use this- */

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.